MongoDB Aggregation the same collection
Collection users:
    _id: ObjectId,
    name: 'string',
    requests: [
        {
            ref: 'users',
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            default: null
        }
    ],

I need to aggregate the the same collection. So, here is demo data of user one
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "668372606b19b60fbe84e4b9"
  },
  "name": "user1",
  "requests": []
}

this is user two:
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6687c6e1ebe711aac96de69d"
  },
  "name": "user2",
  "requests": [
    {
      "$oid": "668372606b19b60fbe84e4b9"
    }
  ]
}

I need to give id of user2 and aggregate requests array data and return name of user1(array can have more ids)
My query is:
        let requests = await User.aggregate([
            {
                $match: { _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)} //comes from frontend
            },
            { $lookup: {
                    from: "users",
                    let: { requests: "$requests" },
                    pipeline: [
                        { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$requests"] }}},
                    ],
                    as: "requestsData"
                }
            }

        ]);

But it's returns an empty array.

Your query doesn't show empty array. Demo

are you sure you are getting right userId from the fronted which has requests array of ids??

Why don't you do a simple $lookup like this?
